# сохранить данные из множественных полей input

Tags: php, laravel

Используется форма:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                {!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'POST', 'url' => 'api/questions/create']) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('lecture', $lecture->id) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('question', 'Вопрос', ['class' => 'control-label col-sm-2']) !!}
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {!! Form::text('question', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div id="parentId">
                    <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('answer', 'Ответ', ['class' => 'control-label col-sm-2']) !!}
                    <div class="col-sm-10" style="display: inline">
                        {!! Form::text('answer[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                        <a style="float: right;" onclick="return addField()" href="#">добавить поле</a>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        {!! Form::submit('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
```

Её обрабатывает контроллер:

```
private function storeQuestion(Requests\CreateQuestionRequest $request)
{
    $question = Question::create($request->all());

    foreach($request->get('answer') as $item) {
        $item = Answer::create(['answer' => $request->get('answer'), 'right' => true]);
    }
    $question->answers()->save($item);

    return $question;
}
```

Как изменить контроллер чтобы при использовании множества введенных ответов сохранялись все?

Ошибка:

```
ErrorException in /var/www/sdo-ucfpsrt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php line 113: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /var/www/sdo-ucfpsrt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 634 and defined

in Grammar.php line 113
at HandleExceptions->handleError('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /var/www/sdo-ucfpsrt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 634 and defined', '/var/www/sdo-ucfpsrt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php', '113', array('this' => object(MySqlGrammar))) in Grammar.php line 113
at Grammar->parameterize(true) in Grammar.php line 634
at Grammar->compileInsert(object(Builder), array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true, 'updated_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17', 'created_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17')) in Grammar.php line 652
at Grammar->compileInsertGetId(object(Builder), array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true, 'updated_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17', 'created_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17'), 'id') in Builder.php line 1721
at Builder->insertGetId(array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true, 'updated_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17', 'created_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17'), 'id')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'insertGetId'), array(array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true, 'updated_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17', 'created_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17'), 'id')) in Builder.php line 933
at Builder->__call('insertGetId', array(array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true, 'updated_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17', 'created_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17'), 'id')) in Model.php line 1609
at Builder->insertGetId(array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true, 'updated_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17', 'created_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17'), 'id') in Model.php line 1609
at Model->insertAndSetId(object(Builder), array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true, 'updated_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17', 'created_at' => '2016-01-11 09:15:17')) in Model.php line 1579
at Model->performInsert(object(Builder), array()) in Model.php line 1485
at Model->save() in Model.php line 529
at Model::create(array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true)) in QuestionController.php line 92
at QuestionController->storeQuestion(object(CreateQuestionRequest)) in QuestionController.php line 107
at QuestionController->store(object(CreateQuestionRequest))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(QuestionController), 'store'), array(object(CreateQuestionRequest))) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(CreateQuestionRequest))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(QuestionController), object(Route), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(QuestionController), object(Route), object(Request), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController', 'store') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 701
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in IfUserIsAdmin.php line 23
at IfUserIsAdmin->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменять в html answer на answer[] и перебирать их в контроллере через

```
foreach($request->get('answer') as $answer) {
...
}
```

**update**

Если в html объявить форму ввода как item[] вместо item, на

```
$request->get('item')
```

вернется массив. Если проще, ваш код

```
$answer = Answer::create(['answer' => $request->get('answer'), 'right' => true]);
```

можно заменить на

```
 foreach($request->get('answer') as $item) {
     $answer = Answer::create(['answer' => $item, 'right' => true]);
 }
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть полный трейслог ошибки и получившийся код?

Comment: Ну так судя по строке 
    Model::create(array('answer' => array('фвфывфыв', 'asdasd'), 'right' => true))
вы что-то не так делаете, фвфывфыв и asdasd это и есть те два введенных поля, каждое из которых должно сохраниться отдельно?

Comment: А теперь сравните ваш цикл с тем, который привел в примере я. Вы пытаетесь на каждой итерации сохранить весь массив целиком, вместо отдельных элементов, вот и выходит ошибка. Внутри цикла не должно быть повторных вызовов $request->get.

Comment: сейчас исчезла ошибка, но по сохранился только последний из введенных ответов

Comment: Потому что сохранение вызывается вне цикла (следовательно срабатывает только для последнего элемента).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!